# Delay after prepareForSegue before UIStoryboardSegue/View shows up

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I have a simple iOS application written in Swift that is hanging every 2nd time I tap a row to present the next view.

The first time, 3rd, 5th, etc times I select a row it waits for 5-15 seconds and then a modal `MZFormSheetPresentationController` (or whatever modal view) is shown.

If I dismiss and tap the row again (to show the same modal) it appears immediately. If I'm in the delay sequence and I tap somewhere else it triggers the appearance immediately. That made me feel like a main thread issue, but I can't find anywhere I get off track.

I found `prepareForSegue` was missing a super call, but adding it, or commenting entirely has no bearing. Happens regardless of if the Segue kind is Modal or Custom; if it has a custom class or not, if animates is enabled

Sometimes it feels like taps are being dropped entirely (The dismiss button feels especially random).

Comment: Enabling a selection color in the storyboard seems to have improved it drastically. If I disable breakpoints in Xcode and run with highlighting on selection performance is basically perfect (increased tap target of dismiss button as well). If I disable again it's intermittent. If I enable and hit some breakpoints the sporadic behavior is back or it just hangs entirely.

Comment: Do you have any break points that log & continue?

Comment: Yes. I had one. Disabling continue didn't fix it, but removing that break point entirely does seem to resolve the freezing. Is that a known Xcode issue?